# How do I fix the arcane blacksmith glitch?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Even though I have the arcane blacksmith perk, I am unable to upgrade the dark brotherhood shrouded armor, the ancient shrouded armor nor the thieves guild master armor.

It still says I must have the perk to be able to upgrade them.

Removing, re-adding the perk doesn't do it, neither does giving myself a new set of armor.

I can upgrade other enchanted armor just fine (such as the normal thieves guild armor).

Answer (score 1):

Some suggestions based on the article on the Thieves Guild Master armor:

http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Guild_Master%27s_Armor_Set

1. Make sure you have leather to upgrade them;
2. Make sure you're at skill 100, because they're not affected by the perk that reduces the skill requirement for improving armor.
3. Make sure you're using the set you acquired as a quest reward, because sets acquired through pickpocketing and maybe spawning a set in cannot be upgraded.

Answer (score -1):

What perks do you have?  It's my immediate thought that you don't have the required perk to upgrade that armor type.  Try adding the blacksmith perks for light armor types up the left side of the smithing tree.

Comment: Those armor are all leather so shouldn't require any perks, the only two smithing perks I have are steel smith and arcane blacksmith.  Not having the perk doesn't mean you can't upgrade the armor type, it just means its not as effective.  I can still upgrade daedric armor, for instance, without having daedric smithing.

Comment: You're correct.  I should have tried it myself before offering an answer.